# Debezium/Kafka [Zookeeperless] unable to connect with C Sharp code

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I am trying to connect to debezium/kafka with my C sharp code and not able to do so, gives me this error message,

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka-1:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.7
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
        - CLUSTER_ID=5Yr1SIgYQz-b-dgRabWx4g
        - BROKER_ID=1
        - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092
        - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
        - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:29092
        - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
        - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
```

**C# Sharp Producer code**

```
    using Confluent.Kafka;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var config = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = "localhost:29092" };
    using var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build(); 

    try {
    string? state;
    while ((state = Console.ReadLine()) != null){ 
      var value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Weather(state, 70)); 
      var response = await producer.ProduceAsync("weather-topic", new Message<Null, string>{Value = value});
      Console.WriteLine(response.Value);
    }
    }
    catch (ProduceException <Null, String> exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message); 

    }  

    public record Weather(string State, int Temperature);
```

**Error Message:**

```
localhost:29092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion:
might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) orbroker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
     %3|1667769721.692|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| 
[thrd:localhost:29092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
```

Read: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

No matter what set of environment variables I changed. The error message never went away.

Comment: Where is your code running? Its own container or host? Also try with `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092`